# What is the name of this 'alignment' UI element?

Tags: gui-design, conventions, names

I'm trying to convince a team that they should use this 'alignment thingy' in their drawing software.

[image]

What is this called? You can find it for example in Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. Can you elaborate? What exactly is being called? The icon? The practice? Can you include the Illustrator UI?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is very low quality

Comment: What is so unclear? I'm talking about the whole element, so the 9 squares. The Illustrator UI is already added, that's what you're seeing. It's not an icon, it's a functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Reference Point Locator

This is the name in Adobe's applications: transformation reference point Locator.

https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/transforming-objects.html