# What's the name of this 3x3 direction selection control?

Tags: gui-design, interface, terminology

I've noticed this control in a few places, but can't get google to tell me what it's called- what is it?

Text justification in Altium Designer:

[image]

Image anchor in Paint.NET:

[image]

And in Photoshop:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Anchor selector

As the word **anchor** appears in all the captures, the name can be **anchor selector** as described in [this link](https://www.programmersought.com/article/86001140826/).

[image]

*Related answer: [Reference Point Locator](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/129078/115107)*